# Can't find specific ID in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console

I am following a rails tutorial and came across this error `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Page with 'id'=2` after typing this `page = Page.find(2)`. I don't understand why this occurred when since I've been following along step by step. I've checked all of my code for typo's and re-ran my migrations and I still get the same error. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this in the console:

```
Page.pluck(:id)
```

What it does is displays an array of all page ids you have in the database. If the array is empty, it means you have no page records. If it does have some values, for example `[1, 2, 3]` you can load any of those by passing the id to the find method: `page = Page.find(1)`.

---

UPDATE

This is how you can add a record, assuming that it has attributes name and email:

```
user = User.new name: 'John Smith', email: 'john_smith@gmail.com'
user.save!

#other way is to create a user directly:
user = User.create! name: 'John Smith', email: 'john_smith@gmail.com'
```

The "!" sign at the end raises an exception if something went wrong, so you will know what exactly; calling just "save", without "!" will return true/false. It is the same for create! / create

Comment: When I did that the array was empty...but that's the thing that is confusing me, I have no idea why it is empty if I have been following along the tutorial step by step. I really don't want to start this entire tutorial all over @bosskovic

Comment: try to go back in the tutorial to a place where you were adding records, probably this is what went wrong, and you ended up with no records. Or you may add a record now, you just need to remember what attributes  the User model has. I will update the answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks for update! I will be trying this out and hopefully I get caught up and let you know what happens. @bosskovic

Comment: So I went back to the tutorial and did what you said (add those missing records) and picked up from there. Everything seems to be going smoothly now! Guess I just have to be more careful.. @boss

Comment: great! just don't give up :-)

Answer (score 0):

It means you don't have page with id = 2, if you search `page = Page.find_by_id(2)` It will give you nil rather than Error.

Comment: I understand that is what the error is telling me but what I don't understand is why it occurred. When the instructor typed it, the page was found.  Is there anything that I should post that will help determine the cause of this? @Padmanaban Gokula

Comment: You possible have deleted the record with the id =2, please try as @bosskovic suggested to see the list of page ids which is in the table.